# "Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions" even though 'Ubuntu' is installed

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently moved my `wsl` directory to another drive due to low storage in `C:` drive. As per the answer provided in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779801/move-wsl-bash-on-windows-root-filesystem-to-another-hard-drive), I used `lxrunoffline` tool and moved my **Ubuntu** distribution to another drive (`E:\wsl` in my case). As soon as the distribution was moved successfully, I ran `wsl` to test and it worked like a charm.

Everything went fine until one day I accidentally renamed the `E:\wsl` folder to something else. Well, as expected, `wsl` didn't work. Then, I reverted back to the name `wsl` and expected it to work but to my surprise, it didn't find any installed distribution after that even though it's installed...

```
E:> wsl
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
```

[image: Ubuntu installed]

Is there any way to revert back to the old directory or make `wsl` point to a manual location?

**EDIT:** I don't want to reset `Ubuntu` as I want to retain the installed packages and preferences...

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Version 10.0.18362. There indeed is `--import` option but that requires the previously exported `tar` file which I don't have...

Comment: Yeah. It's there, with a key named `(Default)`

Comment: It wasn't before. But after I did a workaround, my problem seems to be fixed successfully and now I can see one subkey which probably is for "Ubuntu"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally found a solution to this problem.

This is as simple as registering the distribution using `lxrunoffline` tool using the `rg` or `register` command.

```
E:\LxRunOffline\LxRunOffline-v3.3.3>lxrunoffline rg
[ERROR] the option '-d' is required but missing

Options:
  -n arg                Name of the distribution
  -d arg                The directory containing the distribution.
  -c arg                The config file to use. This argument is optional.
```

After running the **register** command, I was able to start `wsl` as usual. But that would log you in as a "root" user and would thus start in "/root" directory. I ran the following command to start `wsl` as different user (this is for Ubuntu):

```
ubuntu config --default-user <user-name>
```

Comment: where you downloaded lxrunoffline tool

Comment: @Shakthifuture https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline. Anyway, many new features have come to the `wsl` CLI over the course of time. I would suggest you to check those out as well...

Comment: I am facing the same problem, ubuntu i have installed. Enabled VM and subsystem, installed wsl still i am ubuntu not showing when use "wsl -l -v" command.

Comment: If it possible, please answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858461/windows-subsystem-for-linux-has-no-installed-distributions-even-i-installed-ub

Comment: You can install lxrunoffline via PowerShell with Chocolatey using this command choco install lxrunoffline (you will need to install Chocolatey using PowerShell if its not present follow this link: https://chocolatey.org/courses/installation/installing?method=install-from-powershell-v3)