# C Drive filling unexpectedly when using WSL and EAS for APK creation

Tags: windows, react-native, expo, storage, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I will try my best to explain what is happening.

I am using WSL to create a React-Native APK using EAS (EXPO) local compilation.

My APK is less than 400MB when it saves to my Windows folder. (picture attached)

However, each time I build, I lose nearly 3GB of my C drive.

See pictures of BEFORE, FINISHED (build), and AFTER.

I thought that maybe the WSL Ubuntu VM was growing in size. I performed a diskpart on it and it brought it down from 20GB to 17.8GB. You can also see in the picture the WSL Ubuntu VM does not change in size at all during the process.

I am running out of space fast. Any help is appreciated!!

BEFORE
[image: BEFORE]
FINISHED
[image: FINISHED]
AFTER
[image: AFTER]
APK SIZE
[image: APK SIZE]

Comment: Well, have you used a tool such as WizTree to see if there's something you could move off the C drive? Alternately, you could move the WSL image elsewhere. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779801/move-wsl-bash-on-windows-root-filesystem-to-another-hard-drive

Comment: Thank you, I tried WizTree but nothing stuck out as growing. The WSL image does not get larger with each build.

Answer (score 0):

You can move WSL from C to another drive using the Settings.

1. Go to Settings > App and find WSL
2. Click on Move option and select the new drive in dropdown.
3. Click the Move option.